# i want to get this result in query sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this data in my table usersNB

```
sietID  week nb
AE001   W7  94
AE001   W45 88.1
AE001   W50 41.1
AE002   W7  62
AE002   W45 66.6
AE002   W50 33.2
AE003   W7  4
AE004   W7  12
AE004   W45 14.7
AE004   W50 8
AE005   W7  36.5
AE005   W45 39.7
AE005   W50 26.2
```

if it is possible make sql query to get this result like that

```
siteID   w7   w45    w50
AE001    94   88.1   41.1
AE004    12   14.7   8
```

Comment: Is that a puzzle? Please describe how to get to the result and what you tried to get there.

Comment: I have a table in my database users that contains three columns weekID, siteid, numberUser and data such as I have put up, so I need a sql query that allows me to have the result like this
siteID   w7   w45    w50
AE001    94   88.1   41.1
AE004    12   14.7   8
............
........

Comment: in the field weekID the data are w7, w45, w50, so i want to see that in the column and for each site id and for what week they nymber

Comment: I think the responses above mean: can we see your attempt at a SQL query?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible doing the following query

```
select id.sideID, w7.nb, w45.nb, w50.nb
from usersNB id
left join usersNB w7 on
w7.siteID = id.siteID
and w7.week = 'w7'
left join usersNB w45 on
w45.siteID = id.siteID
and w45.week = 'w45'
left join usersNB w50 on
w50.siteID = id.siteID
and w50.week = 'w50'
where id.siteID in ('AE001', 'AE004')
```